# How should I specify the type when passing a function with or without parameters as component props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import { dehydrate, HydrationBoundary } from '@tanstack/react-query';

import getQueryClient from '@/lib/react-query/getQueryClient';

export async function RQBoundary<T>({
  children,
  queryKey,
  fn,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  queryKey: string[];
  fn: () => Promise<T>;
}) {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey,
    queryFn: fn,
  });
  const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);
  return (
    <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}>{children}</HydrationBoundary>
  );
}


export default function Page() {
  return (
    ...
      <RQBoundary queryKey={['posts']} fn={getPosts}>
        <PostTable />
      </RQBoundary>
    ...
  );
}
```

To configure ssr in react-query, we are creating and using RQBoundary as above.

However, the fetch function sometimes receives functions that require parameters. In this case, since the `RQBoundary` component is of type `fn: () => Promise<T>;`, passing it a function with parameters will result in the following error.

`Type '(id: string) => Promise<ResponsePost>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<ResponsePost>'. Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.`
How can I create a component that can pass parameters to both functions that exist and functions that don't exist?

```
export async function RQParamsBoundary<T>({
  children,
  queryKey,
  fn,
  params
}: {
  params:string
  children: React.ReactNode;
  queryKey: string[];
  fn: (id:string) => Promise<T>;
}) {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey,
    queryFn: ()=>fn(params),
  });
  const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);
  return (
    <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}>{children}</HydrationBoundary>
  );
}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to create another component like this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, Oops, I changed it again

Comment: I really didn't understand what are you trying to do. Can you give us a little more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a union of the two props signatures you expect (one where `fn` doesn't take any parameters and there's no `params`, and one where `fn` expects a string parameter and `params` is a string), then use a generic type parameter to select between those two variants at the call site. Here's a simplified example with unrelated stuff removed:

```typescript
type RQBoundaryParams<T> =
    | {
        fn(id: string): Promise<T>;
        params: string;
    }
    | {
        fn(): Promise<T>;
    };
export function RGBoundary<T, Params extends RQBoundaryParams<T>>(props: Params): React.ReactNode {
    if ("params" in props) {
        const {fn , params } = props;
        fn(params);
    } else {
        const { fn } = props;
        fn();
    }
    return <div/>;
}
```

Assuming we have these two functions, one that doesn't take a parameter and one that does:

```typescript
declare const getPost1: () => Promise<ResponsePost>;
declare const getPost2: (id: string) => Promise<ResponsePost>;
```

...here are examples of using that component:

```typescript
// Works, there are no `params` and `fn` doesn't expect them
const a = <RGBoundary fn={getPost1} />;
// Works, `params` is provided and `fn` expects them
const b = <RGBoundary fn={getPost2} params="x" />;
// Fails, because there is no `params` but `getPost` expects them
const c = <RGBoundary fn={getPost2} />;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgeirgGUYUA7AEwFpgnyYBPMJREgDOkJkKQAFCEPgBeOAG9ycFXAAeALjhMAriABGSKBQC+FbnwEIAigCEIO1iig8JzlCCEAeACoA+OFllVQAfRWDVVUwmAApgFi0ZKE4AcwBKLQkcEGBxXz8KSMiwd09EmGSmFMLVEwi4MKUiqNiMuCzcXKR8mpUzciQ1SFg4TEcMYAgmRABxe0cWZx5fABp20qE4QZgkVk2beacXNygPb38-GLAcMCFMjbbkdBgAOieMADkIFgEm1WBMHAYvgSqdPPg4Jw4NcILc0uFmio0FMZIponA1qCznATIFoTchL0itErg8ibikAAbcQIxHIsTwBSjaa4+Qw25EyIktLk+pEGA6KDTLwsYAANyoBXIdXIPzQlOcAnpqJSSBgUhkAEYtDF4bIAh0cnlkCIUZJpDApXKFUQ4Mr4Kr1RaAEw6+LlSrpQIG7JdLwm0TiDWW8w0OAAdWgAGshGsYAALIwCRXaCBwAAGWM86bgzBYGeiOZYEGETAA5PBBvwMHAE0gQOR7bm8f65g4jjxmbIFI7g5rcZKKGHI1AY2tMxsc7l8RAxfEkPm8wWmDmq0gMJs6w2m-oWwg2wsll2e2rg87cVmhLJ8GoIYPqLQAGIoYDUtaGNAoHQ0uu26dMNMJzBIQc30HR4HTXsLVXIZ1xgTdE23FF4DQPcDw7Y8oJkc84EHIA)